# Create odoo user with admin privileges from psql

Tags: postgresql, odoo, psql, postgresql-12, odoo-17

I lost the admin user's password and reinisilazing with an email did not work (i did not receive an email). so i would like to use PgAdmin to create a new user with admin privileges to access Odoo interface. I am on `Odoo 17` and `PostgreSQL 12`.